# Excel C#: How to get the Worksheet/Workbook name and address from Range object?

Tags: c#, excel

I have a `Excel.Application.SheetChange` event that I register to which passes the range object that changed.

I am trying to extract the Worksheet name, Workbook name and address from that with as little interop calls as possible.

Does anyone have any good ideas? E.g. Like how can I get the **full address** of the the range and then do some string parsing to get it out?

Here is the code snippit:

```
    private void ws_change(Excel.Range target){
        //Code to get target workbook name, worksheet name, and range address
   }
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you show as the code?

Comment: private void ws_change(Excel.Range target){
   //code to get Target workbook name, and worksheet name
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look at the various properties:

```
var sheet = range.Worksheet;
var sheetName = sheet.Name;

var workbook = (Workbook)sheet.Parent;
var workbookName = workbook.Name;
```

If you really want to go down the parsing route, then you can get the fully qualified address of the range by specifying `External = true` in the `Address` indexer:

```
var address = range.Address[true, true, XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, true, null];
// returns e.g. [Book1]Sheet1!A1
```

See the [documentation for Address](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.address.aspx) for details.

Comment: Make sure to use the object Excel.Workbook instead of the interface.